# How to use ZK getFellow() method?

Tags: java, zk

I am passing a bunch of tabs from a zul file to a java file like so:

tabs.zul

```
<tabs>
  <tab id="tab1" label="Tab1"> </tab>
  <tab id="tab2" label="Tab2"> </tab>
</tabs>
<zscript>
  testTabs = new TestTabs();
  Tab[] tabs = {tab1, tab2}
  testTabs.registerTabs(tabs)
</zscript>
```

TestTabs.java

```
public class TestTabs {
  ....
  private HashMap<String,Tab> tabMap;

    void registerTabs (Tab[] tabs) {
      this.tabMap = new HashMap<String,Tab>();
      for (Tab t: tabs) {
        this.tabMap.put(t.getId(),t);
      }
    }

   if(condition) {
     tabMap.get("tab1").setVisible(true);
     tabMap.get("tab2").setVisible(true);
   }  

}
```

Now, I guess using Hashmaps to access a tab is a roundabout way. Using a getFellow(String id) method to access a tab would be much simpler, right ? But, I am not sure how to implement that. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks,
Sony

Comment: 1. What is "ZK"? 2. What do you mean by `getFellow()`? You seem to be using terminology that you assume we would understand, but you aren't defining yourself.

Comment: @matt b: http://tinyurl.com/3w76bgc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

1. Extend *org.zkoss.zul.Window* in your class and link it in your zul file like this:
   `<window id="myWindow" use="package.to.your.ClassThatExtendsWindow">`
   `<!-- your tabs go here -->`
   `</window>`
   Then in your class you can use `Tab tab1 = (Tab) this.getFellow("tab1");`
2. Extend *org.zkoss.zk.ui.util.GenericForwardComposer* and link it in your zul like this:
   `<window id="myWindow" apply="package.to.your.ClassThatExtendsGenericForwardComposer">`
   `<!-- your tabs go here -->`
   `</window>`
   Then in your class declare `private Tab tab1;` and you can use it right away.

Note the differente bewtween the *use* and *apply* keywords. If you use the second approach, make sure that the name of your variable matches the id of your component ("tab1").

Answer (score 1):

The getFellow() method can be used on ZK's component.
Users can get access the component by it's ID

```
myWindow.getFellow("label_1");
```

if you're using ZK MVC way on your application.

you can save your **"composer" into the desktop, then you can access any part of the page.